# How to deal with necromancers ("rises undead" affix)?

Tags: path-of-exile

They typically hide behind their minions and sometimes they get them back to life faster than you kill them.  The necromancer might even be out of your range.
How to safely reach them in this case ?

[image: Sin Lord with rises undead affix]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution is to spam AoE (there are decent amount of AoE's for any class that will come handy) skills to kill him first. They die very fast, so they're really not a problem if focused first.

**Ranger**

Since you're playing a ranger the best skill to use would be [*Rain of Arrows*](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Rain_of_Arrows), it's a skill where you shoot an arrow into air, then a whole rain of arrows falls to the ground, the thing is that the arrows fall exactly where you pointed your mouse cursor before using it, this way not only you can hit monsters that are behind other monsters, you can also use it to attack monsters over walls (and other barricades). The skill is also spamable, you can shoot another volley right after the first hits the ground. Another useful skills for this case would be [*Poison Arrow*](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Poison_Arrow) and [*Split Arrow*](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Split_Arrow).

**Melee**

If you're using melee hero then [Leap Slam](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Leap_Slam) is a great choice, you can use it to jump over enemies and get to the necromancer. If you're more of a dexterity melee and are using daggers, claws or 1H swords then [Whirling Blades](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Whirling_Blades) is a good skill to use to get to the necromancer as it lets you dive throught the enemies.

**Mage**

If you're an mage (INT) character then you can use [Firestorm](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Firestorm), [Ice Spear](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Ice_Spear) or [Lighting Warp](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Lightning_Warp).

Comment: In the case I'm exposing in the question (not in the screenshot), it's not possible because they are surounded with hordes of minions and arrows cannot cross it :(

Comment: @Anto Here you go, i updated my answer. You're probably pass this part of the game already but my answer basically tells you how to deal with your problem with any type of build (class).

Comment: Excellent !  I passed that part indeed, but that type of "summoning" mob I frequent, so thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions I came up with, so far:

- Destroy the minions with the ice elemental which will eventually make them fall into pieces
- Use the [Raise Zombie](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Raise_Zombie) skill gem on their corpses: it should make them disapear before they get a chance to be brought back to life

Comment: There's also Detonate Dead.  Really, anything that denies the corpses to the Necromancer.  Or just ignore his minions and kill him first.